# drupal 7 - How to submit form dynamically

Tags: drupal

I want to submit a form dynamically, without print the form to the user.
I tried something like this:

```
$form = drupal_get_form('my_form');
drupal_process('my_form', $form);
```

But it doesn't work.

Any help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: actually i am not really sure, if this function exists... could you try drupal_process_form() or drupal_form_submit() ?!

Comment: Those function require $form_state variable, How can I get this variable?

Comment: its hard to say, what you have to do with your shown code, but maybe this link helps you: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/what-is-form-state-used-for

Comment: Technically you can't do this by php , why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I wanted to send to paypal the drupal form values, but I managed, I used drupal_go_to($path, @query => array(parameters...));Thanks you!